# How do I post an IFormFile in ASP.Net Core 2.0 Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm working in an application with ASP.Net Core 2.0 and Razor Pages. I have been following the Microsoft Docs on how to upload files to Azure blob storage but I can't get it to work so far.

I have two separate model classes. One for the file upload and one for the Word.

File upload class:

```
public class WordUpload
{
    public IFormFile SoundFile { get; set; }
    public IFormFile SoundFileSentence { get; set; }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class Word
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string AlternativeAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Hint { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Vowels { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Module { get; set; }
    public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Sound { get; set; }
    public string SoundSentence { get; set; }
}
```

Page with WordUpload.SoundFile that is not passed. This is the problem as it always returns null.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IWordRepository _wordRepository;

    public CreateModel(Data.ApplicationDbContext context, IWordRepository wordRepository)
    {
        _context = context;
        _wordRepository = wordRepository;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnGet triggers when the page is opened
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        Word = new Word
        {
            Answer = "",
            AlternativeAnswer = "",
            Hint = "Hint",
            Length = 0,
            Vowels = 0,
            Language = "DK",
            Category = "",
            Module = 0,
            Difficulty = "",
            Sound = "",
            SoundSentence = ""
        };

        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public WordUpload WordUpload { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public Word Word { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Posts the data to the database async
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        // Get the number of vowels in the word
        Word.Vowels = _wordRepository.NumberOfVowels(Word.Answer);

        // Save the length
        Word.Length = Word.Answer.Length;

        // upload file to blob storage
        Word.Sound = _wordRepository.UploadAudio(WordUpload.SoundFile);

        // save to db
        _context.Word.Add(Word);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

And the view - page:

```
@page
@model Fabetio.Web.Pages.Words.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<div class="container-fluid darkblue-background">

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="task--card">

                <div class="dasboard--title">
                    <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
                    <p class="subtitle">Subtitle.</p>
                </div>

                <form method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Word.ID" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.Answer" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.Answer" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.Answer" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.AlternativeAnswer" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.AlternativeAnswer" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.AlternativeAnswer" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.Hint" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.Hint" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.Hint" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.Language" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.Language" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.Language" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.Category" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.Category" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.Category" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.Module" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.Module" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.Module" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Word.Difficulty" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Word.Difficulty" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Word.Difficulty" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="WordUpload.SoundFile" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="WordUpload.SoundFile" type="file" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="WordUpload.SoundFile" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn--blue" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The WordUpload.SoundFile is not passed with the model. When I debug the application, it is returned as null in the controller/page. All the other properties are passed without any issue.

Do you know how to pass the file?

Comment: Take a look at [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads) and pay note to `enctype` attribute.

Comment: It still shows null instead of the file when the form is posted. Do you have any other idea as the why it happens?

Comment: Check the following tutorial [Upload files to a Razor Page in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/uploading-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Have you also considered using one model class. Merge the IFormFile properties into the one model and it should work. From the docs you should also note that you need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to add this on your form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In your post method, if you have any trouble with the model binding not binding the file to your model, you can get to it directly from Form.Files like this:

```
 var formFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
```

you should check first if HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Length > 0 or that code will throw an error. Then copy the bytes to your model to save. 
See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: I just tried adding it to the from but the property remains null when I try to post the form. Do you have any other idea as to what might be causing it?

Comment: @JoeAudette I don't think what you're saying is true, model binding for `IFormFile` should work just fine. My guess is that `multipart/form-data` actually does the trick.

Comment: @HenkMollema you are right, the documentation looks like it should work, but the op said that did not solve it. I will edit my answer to say if you have any trouble with the file model binding you can get it directly from Form.Files

Comment: Ah I see, that's odd. Thanks for the clarification.